# Do feature classes need to be versioned for editing with ArcGIS Collector/feature service?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, feature-service, arcgis-collector

I have an Oracle 18c/10.7.1 geodatabase with feature classes that have the following properties:

- Unversioned
- SDO_GEOMETRY datatype
- Registered with the GDB

---

My organization plans to serve up the feature classes to a feature service/ArcGIS Server for on-premise/live-editing via ArcGIS Collector (not ArcGIS Online).

Do the feature classes need to be versioned in order for users to edit them via Collector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ArcGIS Server -> Enterprise or workgroup geodatabase-specific requirements](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.7/publish-services/windows/prepare-data-for-feature-services.htm)

> Versioned (traditional and branch) and **nonversioned** geodatabase data
>   is supported in feature services. **Esri recommends that you use
>   nonversioned data in feature services because it scales better for
>   editing.** There are some complex data types (for example, network
>   edges), however, that must be versioned before you can edit them
>   through a feature service.